# Changing pagination for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I must change default pagination in WordPress from `url.xxx/page/2/` to `url.xxx/page-2/` is there a way to change that? I tried to use "`format`" param in *`the_posts_pagination()`* function but it redirects me to my homepage and each pagination link add page chunk to previous making url like this: `url.xxx/page-2/page-3/page-4/` and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the paginate_links() function and customize its format

Here is how you can achieve:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
    'format' => '?page-%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

Comment: I used that function but after clicking a link I get properly redirected to desired url BUT wordpress detects this last chunk of url as category slug and set it as query var and my wp query loop shows no results

Comment: You can define your custom rewrite rule using this function

function custom_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array(
        'page-(\d+)/?$' => 'index.php?paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_rewrite_rules'); function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%my_custom_page%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

Comment: I added these 2 functions but somehow wp detects this part of string as query var for attachment slug